# GLX version 1.3 or higher is required

Tags: java

I just tried to run a java jar tool: cov'cop in jdk1.8..:

```
java -jar CovCop.jar
```

I had this error:

```
ES2 Prism: Error - reported GLX version = 1.2
GLX version 1.3 or higher is required
```

I tried to install this ppa:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
```

I also re-installed NVDIA drivers.

This is the output of `sudo lshw -C display`:

```
*-display               
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: SVGA II Adapter
   vendor: VMware
   physical id: f
   bus info: pci@0000:00:0f.0
   version: 00
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=vmwgfx latency=64
   resources: irq:16 ioport:1070(size=16) memory:ec000000-efffffff 
memory:fe000000-fe7fffff memory:c0000000-c0007fff
```

This is the output of `glxinfo | grep -i version`:

```
server glx version string: 1.2
client glx version string: 1.4
GLX version: 1.2
OpenGL core profile version string: 1.3 Mesa 4.0.4
OpenGL version string: 1.3 Mesa 4.0.4
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the outputs of `sudo lshw -C display` and `glxinfo | grep -i version`

Comment: OK so this is running on a vmware virtual machine - in which case I can't really offer much. Maybe consult the vmware documentation e.g. [Using Accelerated 3D Graphics](https://pubs.vmware.com/player-12-linux/index.jsp#com.vmware.player.linux.using.doc/GUID-DB7C4F11-1588-4DD3-BB1F-FBABFA570E3A.html)

Answer (score 4):

Depending on application you can disable hardware graphics acceleration dependency.

The recipe in [Petr's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18773007/8555049) to [How to disable or bypass Hardware Graphics Acceleration(Prism) in JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18754803/how-to-disable-or-bypass-hardware-graphics-accelerationprism-in-javafx) worked to launch AWS EC2 hosted (Xvnc) Java application on local Windows X-terminal.

In your example you could try:

```
java -Dprism.order=sw -jar CovCop.jar
```